# ARMv8 Bare Metal with FASMARMfor a Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: assembly, raspberry-pi3, gpio, bare-metal, fasm

I'm struggling very hard on this. What my program should do is, to blink whatever text I tell it in the code as morse code. But it won't compile...

Here is the full code:

```
BCM2835_BASE = 0x3f200000
GPFSEL1 = 0x04
GPFSEL2 = 0x08
GPSET0 = 0x01c
GPCLR0 = 0x28

SET_BIT3 = 0x08
SET_BIT21 = 0x200000
SET_BIT27 = 0x8000000
SET_BIT19 = 0x80000
STACKP = 0x8000
TIMERADR = 0x3f003004
ONEUNIT = 0x3D090
THREEUNIT = 0xB71B0

format binary as 'img'
include 'LIB\FASMARM.INC'

main:
        mov sp,#0x8000
        ldr r0,[#BCM2835_BASE]
        ldr r1,[#SET_BIT3]
        str r1,[r0,#GPFSEL2]
        ldr r1,[#SET_BIT21]
        ldr r2,[#SET_BIT27]
        str r2,[r0,#GPFSEL1]
        ldr r2,[#SET_BIT19]
        ldr r8,[#TIMERADR]
        ldr r6,[#ONEUNIT]
        ldr r7,[#THREEUNIT]

        bl morse_s
        bl morse_o
        bl morse_s
        bl end_wait
b main

turnon_short:
        push {lr}
        str r1,[r0,#GPSET0]
        str r2,[r0,#GPSET0]
        bl delay_short
        pop {pc}

turnon_long:
        push {lr}
        str r1,[r0,#GPSET0]
        str r2,[r0,#GPSET0]
        bl delay_long
        pop {pc}

turnoff_short:
        push {lr}
        str r1,[r0,#GPCLR0]
        str r2,[r0,#GPCLR0]
        bl delay_short
        pop {pc}

turnoff_long:
        push {lr}
        str r1,[r0,#GPCLR0]
        str r2,[r0,#GPCLR0]
        bl delay_long
        pop {pc}

delay_short:
        push {lr}
        ldr r10,[r8]
        add r10, r10, r6
        bl compare
        pop {pc}

delay_long:
        push {lr}
        ldr r10,[r8]
        add r10, r10, r7
        bl compare
        pop {pc}

compare:
        push {lr}
        delay:
                ldr r9, [r8]
                cmp r10, r9
                bne delay
        pop {pc}

morse_a:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_b:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_c:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_d:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_e:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_f:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_g:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_h:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_i:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_j:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_k:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_l:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_m:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_n:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_o:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_p:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_q:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_r:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_s:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_t:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_u:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_v:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_w:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_x:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_y:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

morse_z:
        push {lr}
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_long
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_short
        bl turnon_short
        bl turnoff_long
        pop {pc}

end_wait:
        push {lr}
        ldr r10,[r8]
        add r10, r10, r7
        add r10, r10, r7
        add r10, r10, r6
        bl compare
        pop {pc}
```

If I take out the part

```
        ldr r0,[#BCM2835_BASE]
        ldr r1,[#SET_BIT3]
        str r1,[r0,#GPFSEL2]
        ldr r1,[#SET_BIT21]
        ldr r2,[#SET_BIT27]
        str r2,[r0,#GPFSEL1]
        ldr r2,[#SET_BIT19]
        ldr r8,[#TIMERADR]
        ldr r6,[#ONEUNIT]
        ldr r7,[#THREEUNIT]
```

it compiles (but ofc won't work). so the errors I made are for sure in that section above. I'm quite sure I missunderstand somthing with the ldr instruction and how it works. Many hours of searching didn't help he to fix this. I hope some of you can do. Very appreciated and thank in advance.

The error message is: Immediate offset out of range (-0xfff to 0xfff)

Comment: It looks like you want to `mov` those values into registers, not `ldr` from them as absolute addresses.

Comment: armv8 but this is 32 bit aarch32 code.  and you said bare metal but what does your bootstrap and linking and other things look like? did you start simple just turn the led on with a few lines of code and see that the infrastructure is right?  then move on to complicated things like this?

Comment: I dont know this assembly language (fasmarm) but it is not uncommon that the [brackets] means that is an address so ldr r1,[#SETBIT3] may mean read from that address although the instruction set doesnt support what you are doing so the assembler is doing the work.  fasm is not the traditional type of assembly on purpose it is a pseudo high level language that does work for you.  if you show the disasembly of this code then it should be obvious what is happening here.